# htaccess rewrite stopped working after update

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using this code in my htaccess file, and I am confident that it is right, but it is not working on my new server. You can find my phpinfo file here: http://www.saint57records.com/test.php. I just updated my apache, so I don't know if it is something there. I have tried finding other information but I can't find any.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/artists/index.php.*
RewriteRule    ^artists/(.+)$    artists/index.php?artist=$1 [L]
```

Comment: I had this problem and I solved it by adding `Options -MultiViews` to turn off the feature. Solved my rewrite problems!

Comment: Where did you add it?

Comment: If `Options -MultiViews` doesn't work (add it to .htaccess), check this answer: http://serverfault.com/questions/77347/why-is-this-mod-rewrite-rewriterule-directive-not-working-in-the-htaccess-file/77362#77362

Comment: Between `RewriteEngine On` and the conditions.

Comment: neither of those answers work

Comment: Is the last period in your rewrite condition supposed to be there? don't see too many files with more than one extension..

Comment: but i'm no htaccess guru..

Comment: The rewrite is fine because it worked before I updated Apache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check `httpd.conf` or `apache2.conf` inside  , `AllowOverride` must be set to `All`

If you are using `Ubuntu` check this in **/etc/apache2/apache2.conf**

```
<Directory /your/directory>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```